# Compare the last item in an array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create code in order to run the *Towers of Hanoi* game. At the moment I am still writing on paper and have not yet written much code. However I am stuck on what to do when trying to create a check to see if the item being moved is larger or smaller than the last item in the Stack/array it is being moved to. Any suggestion would be very helpful. Also I'm currently using Python 3.5.0.

*This function should take moves from the user and check to make sure the moves
are valid. Such as checking the length of the guess as well as if it is a
number and also to check to make sure the item is smaller than the last item
in the stack that it is moving to. If it passes all of these it should return
the array and append to the stack.*

```
   if frompeg == 'c':
    if c != []:
        temp = c.pop()
    else:
        print('Error Popping c')
        return ()

if topeg == 'c':
    if c == []:
        c.append(temp)
    elif temp < c[-1]:
        c.append(temp)

    else:
        print('Error')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if frompeg == 'c':
        if c != []:
            temp = c.pop()
        else:
            print('Error Popping c')
            return ()

   if topeg == 'c':
        if c == []:
            c.append(temp)
        elif temp < c[-1]:
            c.append(temp)

        else:
            print('Error')


print(a,b,c)
guess2('a','b')
print(a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `list`s¹ as stack and `append()` to push values onto the stack and `pop()` to fetch values from the stack then you have to access the last element of the `list` to get the value at the top of the stack.  This can be done by negative index values:

```
stack = [3, 2, 1]
print(stack[-1])  # Prints: 1
```

You have to check if the lists are empty before accessing the values.  The source stack must not be empty and if the target stack is empty the move would be okay:

```
def check_tos_values(source, target):
    if not source:
        raise ValueError('source stack is empty')
    return not target or source[-1] < target[-1]
```

Encapsulating the lists in a `Stack` class with methods like `is_empty()` and  `top_of_stack()` would lead to more readable code.

```
def check_tos_values(source, target):
    if source.is_empty():
        raise ValueError('source stack is empty')
    return target.is_empty() or source.top_of_stack() < target.top_of_stack()
```

---

¹ Please use the correct term as there are also array types in Python (`array` module in the standard library and Numpy's array types) which are different from the type `list`.

Comment: Thanks for this, however I knew how to get the last item, I just don't know how to check to make sure the item is smaller than the last item in the stack that it is moving to

Comment: Well like with any other value you can use comparison operators like `<` or `>`. I've updated the answer with a function that does this check.

Answer (score -1):

A = floor(rand(100, 100) * 1000);
contains5 = any(A(:) == 5);
try something like this

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing here with this. I've got the three stacks: a= [4,5] b = [2,3] c=[1] but I want to compare the top item from stack a (so 4) to the last item that was entered into the stack b for example